# vertical-align:middle; not working in my <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I created a  but it's not aligning my text to the . I've tried adding !important but the results are still not working. How can I fix this?

Here is my code below:

```html
  <div>
       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
  
       <!--Bullet 1 -->
       <tr>
       <td align="center" style="background-color:#dc1f26;height: 26px; width: 26px; border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block;color: #ffffff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;vertical-align: middle!important;">1
     </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Please help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about adding span for the text?

`<span style="display:flex; height:100%; align-items:center; justify-content:center;">1</span>`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This does not answer the question. Please answer the question if you are using answers otherwise, please use comments. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It looked like you were suggesting new code without any reason. Like "maybe use this instead this other bit of code that wasn't apart of the question". Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The `display: inline-block;` renders the `vertical-align` ineffective.

**Explanation:** `vertical-align` is only valid for `display: table-cell`. So, if you change the display mode, the alignment becomes invalid.

**Solution:** Remove the `display` from the CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height:26px` on `td`

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="background-color:#dc1f26;height: 26px; width: 26px; border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block;color: #ffffff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;vertical-align: middle!important; line-height: 26px;">1 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the both of "display:inline-block" and "vertical-align:middle" then add "text-align: center".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).